# I get a syntax error when running "webpack --mode production" on heroku

Tags: heroku, webpack, syntax-error

I've upgraded pretty much all libs in the package.json files to resolve a few security vulnerabilities warnings of NPM.

When I deploy to Heroku this what I get in the build output:

```
heroku /assets/node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:39         
remote:        compilation.hooks.additionalAssets.tapAsync('copy-webpack-plugin', async callback => {         
remote:        ^^^^^         
remote:        SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I've searched a lot, but all I could found is some issues for people with windows machines. Obviously this is not my case.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Initially I thought I should disable the heroku build cache, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a newer node version in the buildback config file (phoenix_static_buildpack.config) fixed all the issues.

```
node_version=10.22.0
npm_version=6.14.6
```